# Find the interval between two time spans

Tags: c++, caching

I am given a task. Shortly, I have a orbit of an object that is calculated by the:

```
Cache.orbit = (Cache.last_time_changed - current_time)/2;
```

I have originally used the

```
Cache.last_time_changed = time(0);
```

and when I need to calculate orbit:

```
current_time = time(0);
```

but I am not quite sure if it is right or not. In task, it is not indicated what exactly current_time should be: days, months, or years. But since it is a cache I guess it must be everything together.
What is the best way to calculate this orbit?

Comment: What do you do with this orbit?

Comment: @SparKot order the Caches depending on this orbit value

Comment: If the items with lowest `orbit` value will be removed from the cache first, then this logic is sound. Numeric values are the best data type for performance.

Comment: Why do you have to divide difference by `2`?

Comment: @SparKot I have no idea XD, this is what my task wants me to do